# Problemas ao inserir imagem em um Button

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps

Estou tendo problemas ao inserir uma imagem do pacote "PackIconFontAwesome" em um button. Eu instalei o pacote de Icons do Mahapps e referenciei na minha view, só que aparece um erro conforme a imagem abaixo. O que está faltando?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatButton.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Red.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Referência naminha view:**

```
xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
```

**Código do Button:**

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <iconpacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Cookie"
                    Margin="4 4 2 4"
                    Width="24"
                    Height="24"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test"
    Margin="2 4 4 4"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione a referência

```
xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
```

[Fonte](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/wiki/Usage)